# How to deal with more than one scope in an Angular directive?

Tags: angularjs

Using directives I ended stuck when I needed to have more than one scope.
I'm building a data visualization app with Mongoose Node, Express and D3JS.

Here's the directive

```
angular.module('prodsChart', [])
.controller('businessCtrl', ['$scope','$http', 'BusinessSrv', 'Products', function($scope, $http, $location, BusinessSrv, Products) {

    Products.get()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.products = data;
        });

    BusinessSrv.getTotal()
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.businessSales = data;
        });
}])

.directive( 'saleProd',  [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, element) {

            // Building the chart here

            }
```

And the HTML :

```
<sale-prod></sale-prod>
```

Is it good to inject that way the Services in the Directive ?

Now I have 2 set of data in two $scope. 
How do I use them in the directive ?

Comment: More preferred is the use of shared service between controllers and directives

Comment: @IvanMalenko I updated my Question, should I do it that way ? But then, how do I access the 2 set of data in the Directive ? Before I used an isolated scope but didn't really needed it as I don't need two-way data binding.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question properly but it seems to me that you could create 2 different objects to hold the data and then attach these objects to the scope.  `scope.dataObject1 = {someData: firstData, moreData: secondData }`. You could create as many of these objects as you want.

Comment: @adnpwd I do not see in your example service injection in directive. You inject 2 services in controller only. Need more code. Please, use sandbox for you example or edit you question with snippet. Let me give a couple of examples in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1st and 2nd example directive is in controller's scope and controller's datasets transferred to the directive as attributes. In 1st example directive can modify controller's data. In 2nd example directive use controllers data as strings and creates 2 objects 'productsObj' and 'salesObj' and can't modify parent's scope. It depends on how you handle attributes in the directive and how to transfer them into it. Just click on items in 'Product list (directive)' section and you'll see result.

1st: http://plnkr.co/edit/v46oEGHvUnxMNYsKAeaW?p=preview

```
var directive = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'directive-template.html',
        scope: {
            products: '=',
            sales: '='
        }
    };
};
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="BusinessController as BusinessCtrl">
    <sale-prod products="BusinessCtrl.products" sales="BusinessCtrl.sales"></sale-prod>
</div>
```

2nd: http://plnkr.co/edit/7CyIsqBNLbeZjyfbkGo9?p=preview

```
var directive = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: 'directive-template.html',
        scope: {
            products: '@',
            sales: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('products', function(newVal) {
                scope.productsObj = angular.fromJson(newVal);
            });

            attrs.$observe('sales', function(newVal) {
                scope.salesObj = angular.fromJson(newVal);
            });
        }
    };
};
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="BusinessController as BusinessCtrl">
    <sale-prod products="{{BusinessCtrl.products}}" sales="{{BusinessCtrl.sales}}"></sale-prod>
</div>
```

3rd example is just a piece of code that show's how to inject service in directive and controller. I add it because in you example i didn't see service injection in directive:

```
(function(undefined) {
    var app = angular.module('prodsChart', []);

    var controller = function($scope, Business, Products) {
        // controller logic
    };

    var directive = function(Business) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                // here you can use all Business service logic
            }
        };
    };

    var serviceBusiness = function() {
        // business service logic
    };

    var serviceProducts = function() {
        // products service logic
    };

    app.controller('BusinessController', ['$scope', 'Business', 'Products', controller])
        .directive('saleProd', ['Business', directive])
        .service('Business', serviceBusiness)
        .service('Products', serviceProducts);
})();
```

html:

```
<div ng-controller="BusinessController as BusinessCtrl"></div>
<sale-prod></sale-prod>
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer it helps a lot. Just one last thing, when you write `<sale-prod products="BusinessCtrl.products" sales="BusinessCtrl.sales"></sale-prod>`, it uses an array from the Controller, but I have already all my data in $scope. Do I need to transfer the data this way or I can use the $scope in the directive ?

Comment: @adnpwd You need to learn more about the scopes and scope hierarchies. Read this article https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope. In short, scopes of directives and controllers are referenced to the different models. You can also use this resource to learn more http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbn1OgGei-DV7aSRo_HaAiw

Answer (score 1):

You can inject the `$rootScope` into your directive:

```
angular.module('prodsChart', [])
    .directive( 'saleProd', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    // your code here
}]);
```

and then use it everywhere within the directive.

Comment: Actually I tried to inject the `$rootScope` but I'm not able to retrieve datas. I tried this in the link function, without result :  `var toto = $rootScope.businessSales;
console.log(toto);`

Comment: Are you sure you are attaching the `businessSales` property to the `$rootScope` prior to the directive link function?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the `businessSales` property is set in the controller, in a separate module

Comment: If it's in a separate module, maybe your module should depend on that one? And most likely the `$rootScope` objects are different between modules.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I've changed my code to have only one module and be sure that the scope is the good one.

Answer (score 0):

You could inject a Service into a directive and use it to bring data across the application or use [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit).

A less elegant solution would be using a [.value()](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) and deal with it everywhere in your application.